# In setup.py , how to install dependencies in python lib directory while installing the package itself in a different local directory?

Tags: python, pypi, setup.py, python-packaging

I created a Pypi package and uploaded it.

pyaml is a dependency needed by this package so I added the following lines in setup.py

```
 install_requires=[
  "PyYAML >= 6.0",
        ],
```

now i need to install the package in C:\tools , so I used this command

```
python -m pip install <packagename==packageversion> -t C:\tools
```

but in this case pyaml is installed in the same folder ,C:\tools, and I need it to be installed in Python\Python311\Lib

is there a way to do this without using requirements.pip to install the pyaml separately ?

Comment: [Please read about Python virtual environments and how to create one where to install packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/)